# Check for Null Response from API

Tags: apex, api

I am getting below Response from the API

```
{
"APIResponse": {
    "APIResult": []
}}
```

I have done a null check like below and storing the result in Map

```
if(Response != null && Response.containsKey('APIResult') && Response.get('APIResult') != null && Response.get('APIResult') != ''){
   Result = (map<string, object>)Response.get('APIResult');
```

But this is giving me the error

> common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List to Map

How can I do a null check here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your response code  APIResult is type of Array all you can do is if Array size > 0 consider that list is not empty or you can use List.isEmpty() method to check your APIResult as got any values.

Here is the example code

```
String response = '{ "APIResponse": { "APIResult": [] } }';
Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response);

List<object> apiResponse = (List<Object>)responseMap.get('APIResult');
if(apiResponse!=null){
    // Process your logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

APIResult is of type list and not a key value pair map. So convert it into list.

```
 list< object> Result = (list< object>)Response.get('APIResult');
```

and then you can check size of this list

```
if(Result.size() > 0) {

}
```

You can alsu use apex class to easily parse this JSON

```
public class fromJSON{
    public cls_APIResponse APIResponse;
    class cls_APIResponse {
        public cls_APIResult[] APIResult;
    }
    class cls_APIResult {
    }
    public static fromJSON parse(String json){
        return (fromJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, fromJSON.class);
    }

    static testMethod void testParse() {
        String json=        '{'+
        '"APIResponse": {'+
        '    "APIResult": []'+
        '}}';
        fromJSON obj = parse(json);
        System.assert(obj != null);
    }
}
```